# Error message: "unexpected termination of script, debugging ended", when debugging PHP with Xdebug and Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse, xdebug

I'm getting the following error when debugging:

[image: Error message]

php.ini settings:

```
 xdebug.remote_enable=true
 xdebug.remote_host=localhost
 xdebug.remote_port=9000
 xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
```

Comment: use wireshark to see what data are exchanged between xdebug and eclipse.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming no syntax errors, make sure that you do not have any watches that cause the script to crash as the debugger attempts to evaluate them.

From my experience, this is the most common cause for such early death.

Regardless of that, you may also wish to change your internal web browser, as IE tends to provide cryptic error messages, or use an external browser session (and use remote debugging).

Comment: Removing the watch expressions resolved that error for me. Thanks MasterAM!

Comment: how can i remove watch expressions?

Comment: Go to Expression view, right click, remove all watches. Restart session. See [this](http://www.cleancode.co.nz/blog/57/debugging-error-eclipse-php) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using mod_fcgid in your apache

the default value which is set for FcgidIOTimeout is 40 seconds so you get this xdebug to terminate in 40 seconds

to changed this value you need add the following line in you apache httpd.conf file

```
FcgidIOTimeout 600
```

this is for 10 minutes you can set this value to any other time limit according your requirement

even i had the same problem i found this solution for further details follow the links below

http://jonathonhill.net/2011-05-05/uploading-large-files/  (related link which gives info about the value)
http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html ( and search for  FcgidIOTimeout)

Answer (score 1):

removing watch expressions solved this issue for me

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue on a different platform.

Running x64 linux with Eclipse 3.7.2, PHP 5.4.3 and Xdebug 2.2.0, this error message may appear when viewing variables.

See Xorg [issue #797](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=797)  and [issue #824](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=824).

I can confirm that this issue **is not** resolved in release 2.2.0. The resolution is committed *after* 2.2.0, so you'll have to download a [git copy](https://github.com/derickr/xdebug) (check [the download page](http://www.xdebug.org/download.php)).

After compiling the git version, the issue at hand is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this problem, after Googling for awhile I decided to revert back to 2.2rc because it's the latest version that this issue does not occur (actually not "always" but "sometimes", just need to relaunch).

Before that I've tried 2.3dev too with no luck.